# A simple debut puzzle

Tags: mathematics

It's my first time here, so I'm just chumping out a random puzzle I found interesting. It is the following:

1 + 7 = 6

2 + 6 = 4

3 + 10 = 6

5 + 2 = ?

It's probably super easy for you geniuses because I've been the level of ability here, but I just wanted to have throw something out there.

Comment: Ugh, I hate when people abuse the + and = signs.

Comment: Does + mean something else here?

Comment: Hello! Thanks for posting your question! Unfortunately, I'm not sure it's a good fit for this site. We prefer puzzles that have one demonstrably correct answer, especially for mathematical puzzles. But [as discussed in this thread](http://meta.puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/1435/should-whats-the-missing-number-in-the-series-x-be-allowed), puzzles where you're given a mystery function and have to guess one of the numbers can arguably have a large number of valid answers. This isn't to say that your puzzle is bad, just that it isn't the best fit for this particular site.

Comment: Oh. I'll try to give a better puzzle next time, thanks for the heads up!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

One possibility is

> 5

Because

> You're spelling out the numbers, adding the number of letters, and subtracting 2.
>
> ONESEVEN is 8 letters; 8-2=6
> TWOSIX is 6 letters; 6-2=4
> THREETEN is 8 letters; 8-2=6
> FIVETWO is 7 letters; 7-2=5

Answer (score 19):

My guess is

> 7

Because

> You're summing the number of vertices in each number:
>
>   [[image: picture]]

(However, as that isn't necessarily very mathematical, I don't necessarily think this is the right answer.

Comment: This seems a viable answer, as any, to me.

Comment: If this answer is correct, the puzzle is rather disappointing, because this is not an equivalence relation (not symmetric). 6 only has one vertex.

Comment: It's not the answer, but I must admit it's pretty genius.

Answer (score 3):

My guess is …

> 5

Because …

> Counting the letters in the english language words for each number and subtracting two gives:
>
>  one + seven = 8 letters; 8 - 2 = 6
>
>  two + six = 6 letters; 6 - 2 = 4
>
>  three + ten = 8 letters; 8 - 2 = 6
>
>  five + two = 7 letters; 7 - 2 = 5

Comment: Rats. @BenM ninja'd me :)

Answer (score 0):

5, because you might be adding the number of syllables in each line?  = can be "equals" or "is"?

Comment: But the first and third lines have different numbers of syllables yet are both 6.

Comment: one plus sev en e quals = 6 syllables
three plus one zer o is = 6 syllables